# Add .dll reference to nuget that is generated before build

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I'm deploying a MsBuild task using nuget, that generates a .dll before each build.

I fail to get the generated dll referenced in the `References` node in the Visual Studio project of consumers.

I'm also using MSBuild to build the `.nupkg` file. Generating and compiling works just fine, I deploy the following target in the `build/`directory

```xml
    <Project> 
        <!-- this will automatically run before the 'Build' target -->
        <Target Name="GenerateAndBuild"  BeforeTargets="Build">
             <!--the deployed task that generates the code-->
             <Utils.CreateUtilResourceTask/>

             <ItemGroup>
               <CompileGeneratedSources Include="GeneratedClass.cs" />
             </ItemGroup>
             <MakeDir Directories="$(OutputPath)" Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)')" />

            <Csc Sources="@(CompileGeneratedSources )" OutputAssembly="$(OutputPath)Util.dll" TargetType="library" EmitDebugInformation="true" />
            <Delete Files="@(CompileGeneratedSources )" />
        </Target>
    </Project>
```

That generates the `util.dll` in the project output folder but I fail to get it referenced in the consuming project. 
I thought that this would work in the `.csproj` file:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net46</TargetFrameworks>
    <BuildOutputTargetFolder>tasks</BuildOutputTargetFolder>
    <VersionPrefix>0.1.1</VersionPrefix>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</PackageOutputPath>

    <PackageId>BuildUtil</PackageId>
    <!-- that does not add a refenrece in consuming projects -->
    <references>
      <reference file="$(OutputPath)Util.dll"/>
    </references>

    <files>
      <file src="$(OutputPath)Util.dll"/>
    </files>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Perhaps someone has a hint on that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the assembly reference in an [ItemGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/itemgroup-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019), not a PropertyGroup. For example:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="$(OutputPath)Util.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```